# Filter field suffix in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

My table has the following fields as an example:

```
id
name
image_name_suffix1
image_name_suffix2
color_suffix1
color_suffix2
...
```

I wonder if it's possible to query the following 2 sets, based on suffix(all fieds + those with particular suffix _suffix1 or _suffix2):

```
id
name
image_name_suffix1
color_suffix1

id
name
image_name_suffix2
color_suffix2
```

Can I do this in mysql or should filter in PHP? Not possible to redesign tables and separate them.

UPDATE:

Query like this `SELECT id, name, *_suffix1 WHERE...` is what I'm after.

Comment: Umm just SELECT the respective fields?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, 
       name,
       image_name_suffix1 as image_name_suffix,
       color_suffix1 as color_suffix
 WHERE ...
UNION
SELECT id, 
       name,
       image_name_suffix2 as image_name_suffix,
       color_suffix2 as color_suffix
 WHERE ...
```

or normalise your tables

Comment: What I mean is to automate SELECT and specify `_suffix1` in query instead of all fields containing suffixes. Probably I didn't explain well in original question. E.g. `SELECT id, name, *_suffix1 WHERE...`

Comment: Then the answer is No: You really should normalise and have separate image_name_suffix and color_suffix tables with that 1,2,3,4 etc in its own column